# Samba share of 1.6TB Exfat partition only shows 215 GB

Tags: server, partitioning, mount, filesystem, samba

I recently set a samba share on my Ubuntu server. I have a partition which is 1.6T mounted to it, however it only shows 215 GB on both Windows and Mac machines connected to it.

Partition is sda2:

[image: Partition is sda2]

Again shows as 1.6TB:

[image: Again shows as 1.6T]

Partition is mounted:

[image: Partition is mounted]

Windows:

[image: Windows]

Mac:

[image: Mac]

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the way I was mounting the drive. since the drive is exfat and unix permissions don't apply, I had to specify which group is allowed to use it in the mount:

```
/dev/sda2 /mnt/sambashare/NAS exfat defaults,rw,uid=1000,gid=YOUR_GID,umask=002 0 0
```